# How to make an AJAX call in Cordova 8.0?

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, content-security-policy

I am building an android app with Cordova. The app can successfully make AJAX calls to my server when emulated in my PC browser. However, the AJAX calls wouldn't work in an Android phone, returning a 'NOT FOUND' error message.

To test things out, I tried to use the wildcard * everywhere:

In config.xml, I included the following:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Then, in my index.html, I had this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  *">
```

There have been a few discussions about Cordova AJAX calls in StackOverflow but none has seemed helpful.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 and added cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3. It is working now!